# What's the difference between portal and newly introduced salesforce community

Tags: customer-portal, partner-portal, community

After introduction with salesforce community, I am unable to clear how community is different from portal functionality. I already read [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14539/how-are-sites-partner-portal-customer-portal-and-communities-different-from-ea) but this don't have answers of question like:

- What is new things being provided by community?
- What are restriction we have if we use community?
- Advantage of community over portal.
- Is it capable of provide Email functionalities as same we have in other organization types?
- Role of chatter in communities etc.
- Is their difference between portal user and community user?

I already know that community is dedicated feature for portal functionality, but is it have some new functionality or only a portal part is separated?

Please provide some summary, links or answers you have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Communities launched in [Summer'13](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf).

Before : Partner and Customer Portals

Now : Communities with Partner and Customer Licenses

Before : Limited customisation

Now : Pixel perfect customisation, including customisation of login pages. Use of Site.Com as well as VF Pages for Customisation. Also some ability to customise email with branding.

Before : No Chatter

Now : Chatter with controls to limit people to groups, limit posts to just internal audience and / or external.

Customers who have Portal Licenses can either swap for Community Licenses, or use their existing licenses to use Communities. Also customers who already have Portal can continue to use them, I don't believe an EOL has been announced yet.

Internal Users can switch between communities, similarly to how we can switch between applications. Communities also support SSO.

Answer (score 0):

I got answers for all your questions in here. Please reference to the following address
http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_portal_to_community_migration_cheatsheet.pdf

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Kate Luu

Comment: It's fine to provide a link to an answer, but please provide a sentence or two of explanation.